# Appending elements of a list into a multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, pandas, list, web-scraping, append

Hi I'm doing some web scraping with NBA Data in python on [this page](https://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/injuries.fcgi).  Some elements of basketball-reference are easy to scrape, but this one is giving me some trouble with my lack of python knowledge.

I'm able to grab the data and column headers I want, but I end up with 2 lists of data that I need to combine by their index (i think?) so that index 0 of player_injury_info lines up with index 0 of player_names etc, which I dont know how to do.

Below I've pasted some code that you can follow along.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/injuries.fcgi"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# this correctly gives me the 4 column headers i want (Player, Team, Update, Description)
headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]

# 2 lists - player_injury_info and player_names.  they need to be combined.
rows = soup.findAll('tr')
player_injury_info = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
            for i in range(len(rows))]
player_injury_info = player_injury_info[1:] # removing first element bc dont need it

player_names = [[th.getText() for th in rows[i].findAll('th')]
            for i in range(len(rows))]
player_names = player_names[1:]             # removing first element bc dont need it

### joining the lists in the correct order- the part i dont know how to do
player_list = player_names.append(player_injury_info)

### this should give me the data frame i want if i can get player_injury_info into the right format.
injury_data = pd.DataFrame(player_injury_info, columns = headers)
```

There might be an easier way to web scrape the data into all 1 list / data frame?  Or maybe it's fine to just join the 2 lists together like I'm trying to do.  But if anybody was able to follow along and can offer a solution I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let pandas do the parse of the table for you.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/injuries.fcgi"
injury_data = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(injury_data)
              Player  ...                                        Description
0     Onyeka Okongwu  ...  Out (Shoulder) - The Hawks announced that Okon...
1       Jaylen Brown  ...  Out (Wrist) - The Celtics announced that Brown...
2         Coby White  ...  Out (Shoulder) - The Bulls announced that Whit...
3     Taurean Prince  ...  Out (Ankle) - The Cavaliers announced F Taurea...
4       Jamal Murray  ...  Out (Knee) - Murray is recovering from a torn ...
5      Klay Thompson  ...  Out (Right Achilles) - Thompson is on track to...
6      James Wiseman  ...  Out (Knee) - Wiseman is on track to be ready b...
7        T.J. Warren  ...  Out (Foot) - Warren underwent foot surgery and...
8        Serge Ibaka  ...  Out (Back) - The Clippers announced Serge Ibak...
9      Kawhi Leonard  ...  Out (Knee) - The Clippers announced Kawhi Leon...
10    Victor Oladipo  ...  Out (Knee) - Oladipo could be cleared for full...
11  Donte DiVincenzo  ...  Out (Foot) - DiVincenzo suffered a tendon inju...
12    Jarrett Culver  ...  Out (Ankle) - The Timberwolves announced Culve...
13    Markelle Fultz  ...  Out (Knee) - Fultz will miss the rest of the s...
14    Jonathan Isaac  ...  Out (Knee) - Isaac is making progress with his...
15       Dario Šarić  ...  Out (Knee) - The Suns announced that Sario has...
16      Zach Collins  ...  Out (Ankle) - The Blazers announced that Colli...
17     Pascal Siakam  ...  Out (Shoulder) - The Raptors announced Pascal ...
18       Deni Avdija  ...  Out (Leg) - The Wizards announced that Avdija ...
19     Thomas Bryant  ...  Out (Left knee) - The Wizards announced that B...

[20 rows x 4 columns]
```

But if you were to iterate it yourself, I'd simply get at the rows (`<tr>` tags), then get the player name in the `<a>` tag, and combine it with that row's `<td>` tags. Then create your dataframe from the list of those:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/injuries.fcgi"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]

trs = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
rows = []
for tr in trs:
    player_name = tr.find('a').text
    data = [player_name] + [x.text for x in tr.find_all('td')]
    rows.append(data)

injury_data = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this (a list of tuples), using zip:

```
players = ["joe", "bill"]
injuries = ["tooth-ache", "mental break"]
list(zip(players, injuries))
```

Result:

```
[('joe', 'tooth-ache'), ('bill', 'mental break')]
```